# Update a table that column names are unknown

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table but i dont know its columns (I only know it has "id (Uniqueidentifier) column").

I can get all columns in the table with the following query:

```
    DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''

    SELECT @columnNames += '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id')
    ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME
```

Now i want to update one record with another record's data...

How can i do this?

Thanks all...

Comment: Not knowing column names for tables you plan to use is a really really bad idea and probably stems from a bad design.

Comment: I agree, but table is dynamicly created in different customers... I wished it was created with 2 tables one with data and other with field names etc... but I had to deal with this quick

Comment: How do you know Which column is which and how to associate the values of these with other values.

Comment: Can you make the String of that SQL, If yes then you simple execute the `sp_executesql`.

Comment: i can make the string of that sql but firstly i have to get first record data and store them anywhere and than update another record...

Comment: @zafiyet, that's waht we said, bad design. Dynamically created tables are a SQl antipattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can build a dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @idfrom int, @idto int
DECLARE @table nvarchar(50)
SET @table = 'MY_TABLE'
SET @idfrom = 5 -- id you are copying from
SET @idto = 2   -- id you are copying to

DECLARE @sqlstring nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columnNames = coalesce(@columnNames, 'SET ') + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']=t2.' + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id') 
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME 

SET @sqlstring = 'update t1 ' +stuff(@columnNames, len(@columnNames),1,'') + ' 
FROM @t t1
join @t t2 on t1.id =' + cast(@idto as varchar) + '
and t2.id = ' + cast(@idfrom as varchar)

EXEC( @sqlstring )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a "insert into table1 ... select .. from table2" type insert string and then execute it with sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE @insertColumnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @selectColumnNames NVARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @insertcolumnNames += ',' + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_1' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id')
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME

SELECT @selectcolumnNames += ',' + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '] '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_2' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id')
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME

sp_executesql ('insert into TABLE_1 ('+@insertcolumnNames+') select '+ @selectcolumnNames +' from TABLE_2');
```

I think something similar to this can work 
(you will need to remove the extra , from the column strings and this is not tested at all, just an idea)

Comment: good idea but i want to update my existing data... if i use insert statement, i have to delete existing data...

Comment: It may be harder but you can create an update string, instead of insert, using a similar method.